# How can I study C# from Stack Overflow

Tags: c#

How can I study C# from Stack Overflow?
I have only the basics of the C# language with some simple exercises; now I want to go to the highest level C# through Stack Overflow, reading any questions tagged "[c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c#)". The questions are not ordered from easiest to hardest.

Do you have any idea on how to learn C# from Stack Overflow?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

**NO, you can't.**

But you can surely get help, when you get stuck at some point. Stack Overflow is a Q&A answers website, which provides answers to code-related questions from users all around the world in various languages, including C#.

Questions asked on Stack Overflow are particular to a project, user and his requirement. Since they are very specific about a particular project, learning from them will be nightmare and hell lot confusing.

I suggest you start some project, like an accounting application or a website. Keep going through, and when you get stuck, post the question on SO; the humble community will definitely get you through.

Or you can read a book, which shows sample applications. You can find [various books on Problem-Design-Solution format](http://www.wrox.com).

Comment: +1. Using SO as the *sole* resource to learn a language will almost certainly make you a problem user. SO is not a replacement for proper fundamental learning materials.

Comment: @Pankaj thank you man .. Can you recommend Video and Which is best appdev or pluralsight

Comment: [HERE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vcsharp/bb798022) , you can find various videos for different types of development in C#. And you can visit [THIS](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/Beginners/) website for referring C# tutorials.

Answer (score 4):

Reading other people's questions can be a good way to learn, but Q&A forums like the various Stack Exchange sites aren't designed to teach you a subject in-depth. As you observe, questions aren't ordered in a way that will help you learn quickly.

Your best bet is use Stack Overflow as a resource, but use a book or other website that's designed for instruction as your primary source. When you come across something in the book that you don't understand, look for related questions on Stack Overflow. With over 2 million questions and counting, it's very likely that someone has asked about the very thing that you're wondering about.

If you really want to learn C# in a way that's strongly connected to Stack Overflow, try reading [*C# in Depth*](http://www.manning.com/skeet2/), written by SO's #1 member, [Jon Skeet](https://stackoverflow.com/users/22656/jon-skeet).

Answer (score 0):

I thinks SE are appropriate for asking question for a situation, For studying something you need to master the basic through structured course or guideline, i thinks other type of media such as book or video is more appropriate. For Video i would recommend Pluralsight for book i would Recommend Head First c#.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to learn C# is to program in C#. This is true for any language. Just pick something and start implementing. Make a tic tac toe game, whatever.

Answer (score 0):

Although I agree with Pankaj's answer for the most part, I must say that it helps going thru SO questions on a particular topic (say semaphores on Linux) just after I have read about it from a text book and written a few practice programs (before I solve a real work problem with it).

You will realize how exactly people are using the api's, different problem solving strategies, the 'right way' to do things, best practices and other data that will help you avoid a lot of mistakes and keep on the right track.

SO questions are all about real problems people face when they are trying to solve real world problems. So it is generally a great experience to read the challenges and issues people face. It is like you are looking at the problems very likely you will face yourself if you tried something similar.

However, since you are really looking to learn the language itself, you are best served with a text book. But be sure to search question on topics you study. More often than not you will find practical tit bits that are not there in text books.

Also, you will be able to fill gaps in your knowledge like 'hey, I didn't know that' or 'hey, that's another way to do that !' or 'hey I must try that !'

Happy coding !